# Is there a way to use more then one key event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this. I want the ability of the `keyup` function for textboxes but I would like it to work with checkboxes as well without having to write another function.

```
$('#title, #business').keyup.change(function() {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <s>[`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)</s> or [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#title, #business').on('keyup change', function() {
  // do something
});    

// Deprecated since jQuery 1.7
$('#title, #business').bind('keyup change', function() {
  // do something
});
```

AhamedMustafaM<sub>+1 to you</sub> is right: as of jQuery 1.7, [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the preferred method to add event listeners.

Comment: I used bind, is there a benefit to using on?

Comment: @MHowey `on()` will also catch elements which are added after the function call.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `on` function like

```
$("input .someclass").on({
  keyup: function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  },
  change: function(){
    $(this).addClass("inside");
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).removeClass("inside");
  }
});
```

As of `jQuery v1.7` , `on` is the preferred method to add even handlers